# How to attach a calculated CSV with MailApp in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

- I have a matrix array with some values that I need to parse to a **CSV file**.
- I have the following code:

```
    let array = [["name1", 2, 3], ["name2", 4, 5], ["name3", 6, 7], ["name4", 8, 9], ["name5", 10, 11]];
    let lineArray = []
    array.forEach((fila, index) => {
         let filaComas = fila.join(',')
         lineArray.push(
            index == 0 ? "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + filaComas: filaComas
         )
     })
     
    let csvContent = lineArray.join("\n");
```

The result is a string like `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,name1,2,3\nname2,4,5\nname3,6,7\nname4,8,9\nname5,10,11`, then I need to send an email with MailApp of Google Apps Script that has this 'CSV' as an attachment for download.

> How can I do this?

Comment: I would save the csv as a file and then use the [attachments option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) in mailApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Attach CSV File

Just add this to your code:

```
    let file = DriveApp.createFile('filename',csvContent);
    MailApp.sendEmail('recipient','subject','body',{attachments:[file]});
```

- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))
- [createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=en#createFile(String,String))

Comment: I had to write `file.setTrashed(true)` as not to fill my Drive with unnecessary files as I would have them as attachments in emails, it works very well, thank you.